# Have Chrome autodetect language before spelling checking?

Tags: google-chrome, language, spell-check

Chrome can automatically spell check emails I am writing in Gmail. I have two language installed: Dutch and English in both UK and US versions. And I type emails in both languages regularly. However, that requires me to switch the setting all the time:

[image]

Can I have Chrome automatically detect which language I am typing my email in, and automatically pick the correct language for spell checking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not seem to be possible currently. See http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95604 at the very bottom. It suggests what you did...

Comment: Thanx for the pointer! I hope to come up with something like autodetect soon.

Comment: FYI: The development status of this issue were changed to "Started" on the chromium project, on 11th of February, so hopefully we will have something soon. See: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5102#c45

Answer (score 10):

You can enable the beta version of "simultaneous spellchecking in multiple languages".

go to `about:flags` and enable `Enable Multilingual Spellchecker`:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this is the default now, and the detection does not works properly (at least not as I think it should). And disabling this does not bring back the option to select the language to spell check.

Comment: changed this parameter to "Enable", restarted chrome, but does not seem to add languages to the context menu... (

Comment: Once enabled, the language options are empty I guess because it auto-detects the language (no need to choose).

Comment: I don't see the option `Enable Multilingual Spellchecker`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic language detection is now a part of chrome. They completely removed the option to select language and of course automatic part fails to detect the right language often.

So now instead of having to choose the language each time, we have to live without spell check at all until it decides to work again.

Comment: sometimes language are similar, and any machine can't say if I need to write "color" or "colour" in American or English, and also sometimes there are only one word to check. Impossible to detect if ust "Presentation" word is written in French or English

Comment: What? Removed the option to select language? I've changed language all the time in Chrome ever since they implemented the spell checking feature and it has never gone away for me.